# How to use jQuery ( or correctly) to add the data of the varible e 'valCookie' to the array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I need an array 'indArray [];' enter the values of the variable 'valCookie' - i.e. indexes on the click, that would have the array stored the cookies and the state of the menu was saved when clicking on the links. How do I implement a competent skid of variable data in an array?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {


  //index array
  var indArray = [];
  var indToCookie;
  var valCookie;


  // take index click element

  $('ul > li  > span').click(function() {
    indToCookie = $('ul > li > span').index(this);
    $.cookie('nav-item', indToCookie);
    valCookie = $.cookie('nav-item');
  });


  $('ul.list-1 > li > span').click(function() {
    $("ul.list-1 ul").toggleClass('active');
  });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

To insert data into an array, you can use `push`.

For example:

```
$('ul > li  > span').click(function() {
    indToCookie = $('ul > li > span').index(this);
    $.cookie('nav-item', indToCookie);
    valCookie = $.cookie('nav-item');
    indArray.push(valCookie); // <-- add this line
});
```